# How can I generate the NOR of two TIMER on STM32?

Tags: stm32, pwm

I use the TIM1 and TIM8 in STM32F4 for generating two different PWM signals with 100kHz frequency. I do not know how can I generate the NOR of these two PWM.
I have attached the[image] PWM.

One way is using the logical gate. However, I am not sure if the logical gate can work on the 100kHz frequency or not.

Comment: Some 74HCxx  gates clock at 50MHz

Comment: This might help, there might not be a way to NOR two timers together but there may be a way to chain them together to get the output you want. https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/c4/1b/56/83/3a/a1/47/64/STM32L4_WDG_TIMERS_GPTIM.pdf/files/STM32L4_WDG_TIMERS_GPTIM.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32L4_WDG_TIMERS_GPTIM.pdf

Comment: How can I reach the third PWM by chaining the Timers (using master and slave)?

Answer (score 0):

Logically why would you want to combine 2 PWM’s

- maybe to XOR delay for  Deadtime on H bridge? Then You need timing specs. for your query.

But the cheapest NOR gate is 2 cents and operates up to 75 MHz @ 1.65 to 5.5V https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g02.pdf

Comment: In H-Bridge we need two PWM signals for each leg. However, in my case, I need three PWM signals for each legal, which means the third PWM is the NOR of the first and second.   Are you sure I can make it with logical NOR without any problem? I doubt if the logical gate can work accurately at 100kHz.

Comment: I have not seen 75MHZ in the datasheet. where can I found the frequency operation?

Comment: Keep looking at the plots…..

Comment: @rezaREZAII Page 11, "good for high speed applications up to 100 Mhz."